# Using 2 jar files in one project

Tags: java, mysql

I am making a billing system using Java and MySQL database. In my project I have 2 portions: administrator and end user. Meaning the admin will use only the administrator portion and the user will use the end user portion. These 2 portions are in one project. Now I want to ask if I can make separate jar files for both portions or will I have to put the 2nd portion in a different project and then make a jar file of end user?

Comment: If you have multiple main methods then you can have different manifest files and create separate jars. Depending on how you are building it, it should be possible to do so by having different build targets but this is not recommended. I would recommend having two projects to build separate jars. 
http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/

Comment: if I make 2 projects for different jars then is not that be difficult to keep both projects ?

Comment: I mean to say if after some time I do some changes in my project then I will have to take care both projects ?

Comment: @clinomaniac reply

Comment: Depending on how large the projects are...the ideal way imo would be to keep the shared classes in a separate jar. Manage dependencies through some dependency manager like maven or gradle and link it all together. When you make changes to a project, it will get the latest changes on each dependent project.